# Login with phonegap and asp.net mvc 4

Tags: cordova, backbone.js, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an organizer with tasks for an user that are saved and managed through a website. For the website I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and backbone.js. Now I want to create a mobile app with PhoneGap. The user will be able to login/register and then he will be able to manage his tasks with his phone/tablet on the go. So my problem is that I don't know how to login and then how to get the tasks from the server.

Now I am using backbone.js and I have an api on the server that manages the tasks. My idea was just to use the same code (only html, css, js) from the ASP.NET MVC and it should work easily but for that api the user has to be logged and for this is used simple membership and web security which are used in the backend part that I am not going to use with the mobile version and I am not sure how exactly is the user going to log in.

Another idea was to check user credentials (with AJAX request to the server that can say if the user has entered valid login data or not) so to have my user id on the phone (local storage or something alike) and then use api on the server that will not need user to be logged in and it will manage the tasks of the user(for which I pass user id). But I think that will be an enormous security hole, because everyone will be able to change tasks only with entering a user id. I already found a login example from Raymond Camden ([See it here](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/11/10/Example-of-serverbased-login-with-PhoneGap)) that maybe can help this idea but it's only for the login part(and it's logging on the device only but still the security hole problem that I explained concerns me)

So I would appreciate it if you please give me some ideas how to realise the log in on the device and how to get data for the user from the server. I would really appreciate even only conceptual ideas.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Web API interface by creating a Web API controller inside your controllers folder to expose your server side code. For authentication, you can use HTTP basic authentication by providing user's credentials in the authorization header. Now in your Web API message handler, you need to read the user's credentials and authorize the user. [Here is a good article on this topic.](http://www.piotrwalat.net/basic-http-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-using-message-handlers/) . One drawback of using basic authentication is that for every request, you need to hit your database of AD to authorize the user. To prevent this, you can create a secure token after the user is authenticated first time and then pass it on to the client so that for all future requests, client use this secure token. if performance is not a big deal for you, basic authentication will do.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation. In order to solve the problem I used Thinktecture framework Session Token. It allows to to authenticate once using for example Basic Authentication, then you can request a token that can be passed among requests and can be store in you local storage. This way you won't have to store the user and password in insecure locations and won't not have to authenticate every per every request.